# Order an array containing file paths by alphabetical order in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

I have an array that contains the full path to many files. I need the array ordered alphabetically, but only by the basename of the file (file1.exe)

For example:

`/path/2/file3.exe`

`/path/2/file4.exe`

`/path/to/file2.exe`

`/path/to/file1.exe`

I expect the output to look like this:

`/path/to/file1.exe`

`/path/to/file2.exe`

`/path/2/file3.exe`

`/path/2/file4.exe`

The hard part I'm having is finding a way to make it ignore the directory when ordering. I will still need the file paths, but I just want it to reorder only factoring the basename, not the whole string.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), with a callback that compares the [`basename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) of each file name. For example:

```
$files = array('/path/to/file3.exe',
               '/path/to/file4.exe',
               '/path/2/file2.exe',
               '/path/2/file1.exe'
              );

usort($files, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp(basename($a), basename($b));
});

print_r($files);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /path/2/file1.exe
    [1] => /path/2/file2.exe
    [2] => /path/to/file3.exe
    [3] => /path/to/file4.exe
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9uOZ5)

Comment: Perfect! After hours of searching, this was it. The only thing I needed to do was make the basenames lowercase and now it works as expected great. Thanks!

Comment: No biggie, I didn't even think about it until I actually implemented it. Thanks again, you have no idea how grateful I am